# Suppose $f $ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying the condition $\{f(x)\}^3-x\{f(x)\}^2-x^2f(x)-2x^3-7x^4+7x^5=0 $

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

Suppose $f $ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb R$ satisfying the condition $$\{f(x)\}^3-x\{f(x)\}^2-x^2f(x)-2x^3-7x^4+7x^5=0 $$ at each $x \in \mathbb R$.

Show that $f'(0)=2$ and evaluate $f'(1)$.

I tried it by differentiating with respect to $x$. but in vain.

Comment: Could you please show how far you got? What values are you using for $f(0)$ and $f(1)$?

Comment: I just differentiated with respect to $x$. The problem is I do not know the value of $f(0)$. It is my problem here.

Comment: Set $x$ to zero in the original equation.

Comment: what do you mean by $ \{ f(x) \}$ ?

Comment: @Santeri Then it would not give the correct answer. @ Learner : brackets

Comment: I see,setting $x=0$ ofcourse gives $f(0)=0$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since obviously $f(0)=0$, set $g(x)=f(x)/x$. This then satisfies 
$$
g^3-g^2-g-2-7x+7x^2=0
$$
Then $g(0)$ is one of the solutions of $y^3-y^2-y-2=0$. $y=2$ is one solution and by polynomial division
$$
(y^3-y^2-y-2):(x-2)=y^2+y+1
$$
has no further real solutions. Since $2$ is a simple root one gets
$$
g(x)=2+O(x)\implies f(x)=2x+O(x^2)
$$

---

$g(1)=f(1)$ is equally one of the solutions of $y^3-y^2-y-2=0$, thus $f(1)=2$ with implicit derivatives obtained from 
$$
g'(3g^2-2g-1)-7+14x=0\implies g'(1)=-1
$$
and $g'(x)=f(x)+xf'(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

@LutzL

Now I have the correct Idea !

Since $f$ is differentiable at each  $x \in \mathbb R$ , $f$ is differentiable at $0$ and $f(0)=0$.

So by the definition $$f'(0)= lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$$

So by dividing the equation by $x^3$ when $x \neq0 ,$ we get that

$(\frac{f(x)}{x})^3−(\frac{f(x)}{x})^2−\frac{f(x)}{x}−2−7x+7x^2=0$

Now take the limit $x \rightarrow0$, then we have $[f'(0)]^3-[f'(0)]^2-[f'(0)]-2=0$

That is $f'(0)=2$